# XHTML 5 standard check (HTML + CSS)

Tags: html, css, xhtml

My web page must be strictly developed using XHTML 5 standard. How can I check it?

Comment: There is no such thing as "XHTML 5". There is XHTML (1.0, 1.1, and there was going to be an XHTML 2.0, but I doubt there ever will) and HTML 5.

Comment: There is XHTML5: “This specification defines version 5 of the XHTML syntax, known as ‘XHTML5’.”
http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml

Comment: Is there any site which you can provide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the W3C validator here: http://validator.w3.org/

on a sidenote: there is no such thing as a XHTML5 standard. The last XHTML version was 2 and the development there has ended. The current standard is just called HTML5.

Answer (score 5):

W3C validator:

http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: my HTML code must follow the strict, well-formed  XHTML syntax. Can I understand it via that site. Moreover I used the cite and there are some errors for example:Line 25, Column 14: End tag div seen, but there were open elements.
        </div> but it seems closed in my html code.

Comment: It may be some characters that is confusing the validator, in which case you should wrap them around `<![CDATA[ Characters here ]]>`. I can only provide more information if I actually see the code that is going through the parser. You can edit this question or (better) open a new one :)

Answer (score 1):

The W3C has an experimental HTML 5 validation engine [here](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri+with_options) you might want to check out.  But since the standard is still in development, I don't think you'll find any definitive validation engines just yet.

Please also keep in mind that there will be no official XHTML5 standard.  HTML 5 will support two formats, one which uses strict XML syntax, and another which uses regular HTML syntax, which is somewhat looser in that it doesn't mandate closing tags or capitalization rules.

To get what you're looking for you might want to try two different validations.  One to check that your document is a fully compliant XML document and also another to run it through the HTML 5 validation engine to check for non conforming tags, etc.

Answer (score 1):

By comparing your code against the rules for XHTML serialization in the HTML5 specification, as soon as it becomes official (allow ten years for delivery). Meanwhile, the so-called HTML5 validators, such as http://validator.nu and the W3C service based on it may be useful, but a) they are known to be incomplete and can probably never check *all* aspects of the rules, b) they do not necessarily reflect the most recent HTML5 draft, and c) the drafts themselves are work in progress and may be changed at any moment without prior notice.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using http://validator.nu/.

Answer (score 0):

Note what Jukka says, but with regard to using either validator.nu or the W3C HTML validator:

If you want to validate a page at a URL as XHTML with the W3C HTML validator, and the page has `<!DOCTYPE html>` as its doctype, then you **must** serve the page with an XML mime type such as `application/xhtml+xml` to the validator.

This is a good thing. Only if you use such a mime type will browsers treat your XHTML as XHTML, otherwise they will treat it as HTML and all your careful XHTML will be be so much tag soup. With HTML5, validators now behave the same way as browsers.